# Updating database ids, what to do with form url

Tags: php, laravel, formbuilder

Updating existing items in DB in my application is solved by this way:

I have url like this:

```
http://localhost/project/public//structure/edit/about-us
```

In router I have set

```
Route::get('/structure/edit/{url}', 'StructureController@update'); //for displaying the prefilled form
Route::post('/structure/edit/{url}', 'StructureController@update'); // for saving new values
```

So it means, I'm building update query `where url = $url` . This is the main part of my view file:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => URL::current()]) !!}
```

I don't know where to point "form action". So I¨m using the same url as current url, so router recognizes, that this is post request and I can process the update inside the same controller and select new (updated) data to my update form.

The problem is, when I update the `url` via form, new value will set to database. So it means, from this moment old url doesn't exists, but and my form action point to url, which doesn't exists anymore. 
What can I do with that? If you know, what I mean...

Comment: Why don't you have a redirect to the new url after saving?  P.S.  You seem to have both post and get pointing to update.

Comment: There is no new url. I would like to stay on the same uro and just show the flash message.

Answer (score 0):

To update use `patch` method instead of `post`. Write this in `web.php`

```
Route::get('/structure/edit/{id}', 'StructureController@edit');
Route::patch('/structure/{id}/update', 'StructureController@update');
```

You can use either `action` or `url` as a form action. Pass the structure id in the second parameter of the `action`

```
{!! Form::model($structure,['action' => ['StructionController@update',$structure->id],'method'=>'patch']) !!}
```

Comment: I have tried this way. I get the no message error: see screen here: https://snag.gy/9GCDoB.jpg

Comment: Recheck the method in `blade` & `routes`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do what @smartrahat suggests and still got the error you posted, then can you run `php artisan route:list` command and show us the structure of your routes?